# Class not printing variable

Tags: php

Im trying to understand objects & classes. But Im having a problem. Im trying to pass a variable from a class into another class.

Why Im doing this is mostly because I want to understand more how classs work but also for future where Im gonna need to send database connection into classes.

Here is my code simplified for the problem:

```
class databaseConnection
{
    public function connect(){

        return "localhost";

    }
}

class like
{

    private $database;

    public function __construct(){

        $this->database = databaseConnection::connect();

    }

    public function addLike()
    {
        return $database;
    }
}

$obj = new like;
echo $obj->addLike();
```

But this doesn't show anything. What i thought the results would be is `echo "localhost";`

Why isn't this working?

Comment: You should turn up error reporting, this would have helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`connect` is not a static method, you should either change it to static or create an instance.

```
// if you use databaseConnection::connect();
public static function connect(){
```

or

```
$db = new databaseConnection;
$this->database = $db->connect();
```

And you also need to change

```
public function addLike()
{ 
    // use $this to access object property
    return $this->database;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `databaseConnection::connect()` as a static method. Modify it to:

```
public static function connect(){ }
```

Edit - as @Shankar Damodaran pointed, also add:

```
public function addLike()
{
    return $this->database;
}
```

Comment: Tried changing that but it still wont output anything

Comment: You need to make use of `return $this->database;` on your `addLike()`

Comment: Oh, your're right @ShankarDamodaran. I have missed it. :(

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should really follow convention and start naming classes StartingWithCapitalLetter.

Secondly, "::" operator is used to call static methods (to put it simply - you don't have to create object of a class to call them, if they are public).

Normally, to call object's method you use operator "->", like $object->method(arguments);
So in your case, you need to first create an object of your databaseConnection class (because you can't call methods on not-initialized methods) and then call "connect" on it, like that:

```
$connection = new databaseConnection();
$database = $connection->connect();
```

To pass a parameter, you need to modify the method declaration

```
public function connect($parameter){
    return "Connecting to " ... $parameter;
}
```

and call it with

```
$database = $connection->connect($parameter);
```

On a sidenote, you should really use parenthesis when creating objects of a class, like:

```
$obj = new like();
echo $obj->addLike();
```

Also, as [deceze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/476/deceze) pointed out, you need to access class variable using $this instead of accessing local method variable:

```
public function addLike()
{
    return $this->database;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function addLike()
{
    return $this->database;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`$database` and `$this->database` are two different variables. `$database` is a local function variable which does not exist, it's not the object property you set before.